# Did Democrats win the popular vote for governor in 2018 by as much as Hillary Clinton did in 2016?

Tags: united-states, voting

I saw a question on Politics Stack Exchange titled [How did Republicans get a majority of governorships and lose the popular vote by almost 3 million votes in 2018?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/53021/how-did-republicans-get-a-majority-of-governorships-and-lose-the-popular-vote-by). This made me think that Democratic governors won the popular vote by about as many votes as Hillary Clinton did in 2016. I am not sure if this is a valid way to talk about this for multiple reasons. But, I am curious. I don't think this is a duplicate because it talks about the national vote total, not why or how this result was reached.

Comment: These are not comparable, because only 36 states voted in Gubernatorial elections in 2018, whereas 50 states voted in the Presidential elections in 2016.

Comment: This is funny. Big blue states elected Democratic governors while most small blue states (and red states) elected Republican governors. Because big states by population by definition have more people, they make a bigger footprint on the popular vote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hilary Clinton won the 2016 presidential popular vote by 2,868,686 votes, or by 2.09% according to the [FEC](https://transition.fec.gov/pubrec/fe2016/federalelections2016.pdf).

In terms of the national vote, the Democrats [won](https://uselectionatlas.org/RESULTS/national.php?year=2018&off=5&elect=0&f=0) the 2018 gubernatorial race by a very similar 2,822,073 votes, but as fewer people voted in these elections, this was larger in percentage terms - 3.07%.

I'm not sure whether you can draw many conclusions from this, for reasons you seem to be aware of by your question, and indeed, are explained in [some of the answers](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/53039/28994) to the question you've linked to.

Comment: That makes sense. I got that information too.